# Causes of slow rendering of app's developed using phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I submitted the example app given by phonegap and received the platform specific apps,after installing them over the device I noticed the rendering to be quite slow...is it true to say that apps developed using phonegap are slow 
Waiting for ur replies.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not really a Question. What example app? What platform? What element is rendering slow ?

Phonegap is based around a native Webview on most devices and will render as such. The speed of your page will be dependent on what you have in your HTML/Javascript. Its a trade off between speed and ability to deploy across many platforms at the same time.

Comment: Yes,the problem is that webview works pretty slow on android devices.
I tried using normal html an css 
Even tried to use jquery but everything seems to be a bit laggy!
So I guess its better to make native apps rather than using phonegap
Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, Native prob will always be quicker in some respects. But most lag can be fixed with code tweaks. For example don't use `<a href/>` tags, replace with `onTouchStart` events which will bypass the native dbl-clicking pause of the webview.

Comment: Ohhk!!
Can you provide me some sites where I would find more tweaks like these....
Actually i'm developing a app which would perform operations over the remote database,so would it be advisable to use phonegap for such apps